# Metallic effects not being exported with gITF 2.0 format

Tags: shaders, file-format

I'm trying to export my model to Sketchfab using the gITF 2.0/.glb file format. Basically, I created and painted my model in Nomad Sculpt, and exported the .glb from there into Blender. Then to get my painted roughness and metallic effects to appear in Blender, I attached a new Vertex Color node to a Converter (Separate XYZ), which I attached to Roughness and Metallic in the Principal BSDF window. (I found these instructions in the Nomad Sculpt online manual.) [This is what my map looks like, as well as my materials tab.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yV4Gy.jpg) I can now see the metallic effects in Blender. However when I export this .glb to Sketchfab, there are still no metallic effects on my model. Actually, I noticed when I re-imported this file in Blender after changing my map, I checked it again and the map looks different (also in my link above). My metallic effect is now also not appearing in Blender anymore. I therefore assume this has to do with some Export setting? Or is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: glTF does not support vertex-painted metallic/roughness. You'll have to unwrap, bake the metallic/roughness into textures, and change your materials to use the textures (see [the manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html#metallic-and-roughness) for the node setup the exporter recognizes).

Comment: Of course, alternatively you could re-hook up the vertex color in Sketchfab just like you did after importing into Blender.

Comment: @scurest "glTF does not support vertex-painted metallic/roughness" how does this make sense if I am able to export my vertex painting with this information in .glb from Nomad Sculpt, and get it to appear properly in Blender? Also, I cannot find  anything related to nodes in the 3D settings for my model on Sketchfab... Maybe there's something I'm missing. (Sorry for the super newbie questions, I'm totally new to the 3D modeling world.)

Comment: Well you aren't able to do that, are you? That's why you have to manually change the matierial nodes in Blender to make it work. You would have to do the equivalent thing in Sketchfab. I have no idea if/how you can do that though since I don't know anything about Sketchfab. If you can't do that, glTF itself only supports constants or texture maps for metallic/roughness.

Comment: @scurest I see. I will try to go the route of baking into textures. Thanks for the response, I really appreciate it!